# How to refresh access token provided by TokenCredential / ClientSecretCredential by Azure Identity Java SDK?

Tags: azure-active-directory, access-token, refresh-token, azure-java-sdk, azure-service-principal

I am trying to obtain an access token using the [Azure Identity Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/identity/azure-identity) and later refresh it using the refresh token.

I use the following SDK:

```xml
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Java code snippet:

```java
  context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false, service);
  ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
  Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(resource, credential, null);
  token = future.get().getAccessToken();
```

In the code snippet, the token has an expiration of 1 hour as expected, see [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#access-tokens).

The [ClientSecretCredential](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/identity/azure-identity/src/main/java/com/azure/identity/ClientSecretCredential.java) implements the [TokenCredential](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/440356b448f384c23e16f9e06a8438f1c13898bc/sdk/core/azure-core/src/main/java/com/azure/core/credential/TokenCredential.java#L12) interface, which describes that refreshing the access token must be individually implemented.

**I couldn't find any example on the Microsoft documentation (or other resources) that describes how to refresh the token using the Java SDK.**

**What is the correct way of refreshing the access token?**

Comment: Do you have to use client credential flow ?

Comment: I am using the token in `StorageCredentialsToken` to initialize a `CloudStorageAccount`. Is there another approach you would suggest when using Service Principals?

Comment: Hi @AndreasHessenthaler, Are you using MSAL or any other library?

Answer (score 1):

When using client credentials authentication, the correct way is to ask for a new token from the ClientSecretCredential object.
What you could use is a wrapper around the ClientSecretCredential that caches the returned token for, say 50 minutes, and then once that time has passed, it asks for a new token from the ClientSecretCredential.

Comment: Asking for a new token works, of course. But I was wondering how I would correctly **refresh** the token, e.g., by using the refresh token from the `future` object - which, however, is null in the code snippet.

Comment: There is no refresh token when using client credentials flow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you point to any documentation and / or code examples which demonstrate your suggested cache mechanism that includes the refresh mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

I think the refresh process is abstracted away by azure-identity.

You can get the expire date via `AccessToken.getExpiresAt`.

For `ClientSecretCredential`, it probably does not need a refresh. SDK only need to fetch a new token (using the same secret), if last one expires.

For other e.g. `InteractiveBrowserCredential` which requires an interactive flow to get a new token, it makes sense for a refresh.
It is handled in azure-identity [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/identity/azure-identity/src/main/java/com/azure/identity/implementation/IdentityClient.java#L553-L564) (you can see when the last token is expired or within 5min of its expire date, it will get force refreshed), and further in MSAL [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/msal4j/AcquireTokenSilentSupplier.java#L55-L59).

Not official answer, just reading the code.