# How do I access secrets from azure key vault using msal to manage token refresh on expiry

Tags: java, azure-ad-msal, azure-java-sdk

Currently, I am using azure key vault using managed identity for authentication. Since I want the library itself to handle the token refresh before expiry, I want to use MSAL for it. Is there any way to do it by providing the same parameters as we provide for ClientSecretCredential (i.e, client_id, client_secret and tenant_id).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refresh access token provided by TokenCredential / ClientSecretCredential by Azure Identity Java SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64460677/how-to-refresh-access-token-provided-by-tokencredential-clientsecretcredential)

Comment: [MSAL - AcquireTokenSilentSupplier.java](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/msal4j/AcquireTokenSilentSupplier.java#L55-L59)